# django errors not emailing

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my first django application. Setting up email logging so that I can debug any server side issues. I have, what I think, is all the right info in the settings file to send exception info via email, but I don't receive any email.

I guess it's possible that the error is happening before anything django actually happens. Anywhoo, is this set up right?

Settings file:

```
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

EMAIL_HOST= 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER='user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

ADMINS = (
    'me', 'myaddress@domain.com',
)

SERVER_EMAIL = 'user@gmail.com'

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'database',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      
        'PORT': '',                      
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = ''

#WSGI_APPLICATION = 'PFM.wsgi.application'

import os
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'templates').replace('\\','/'),)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'finances',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.openid',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {
        'openid':
            {   'SERVERS':
                    [dict(id='yahoo',
                          name='Yahoo',
                          openid_url='http://me.yahoo.com'),
                    dict(id='hyves',
                         name='Hyves',
                         openid_url='http://hyves.nl'),
                    dict(id='google',
                         name='Google',
                         openid_url='https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id')]

            }
    }

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/finances/transactions/"
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/accounts/login"
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your SMTP settings...I use port 465 for smtp.gmail.com when connecting with SSL/TLS.

Comment: hope you are installed django sendmail server too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this settings

```
#  FOR YOUR E-MAILS
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='webmaster@localhost' # or webmaster@servername
SERVER_EMAIL='root@localhost' # or 'root@servername'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost' # or servername
EMAIL_HOST_USER='' # or 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_PORT = 25 #587 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: It turns out the issue was a missing favicon.ico file. So 500 was happening before django even got involved, so no email.

Answer (score 0):

Your settings should also contain a couple of lines for the logging purpose which sends mail when error occurs :

```
# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

this is generated by django once you did

```
python manage.py startproject foobar
```

in your settings.py

You can have a look at it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/logging/

Hope this will help .